# Aerospike - Python Client - NoSQL benchmark

Tags: python, performance, nosql, aerospike

I was performing a NoSQL performance benchmark for a client.  I was wondering if my Aerospike Python code is optimal? I'm trying to record query time and load time. The data has 500,000 rows and 8 columns. My code is below.

```py
def test_db():

    config = {
      'hosts': [ ('127.0.0.1', 3000)  ]
    }

    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

    t0 = time.time()
    global rec
    rec = {}
    with open('skunkworks.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        rownum = 0
        for row in reader:
            # Save First Row with headers
            if rownum == 0:
                header = row
            else:
                colnum = 0
                for col in row:
                    rec[header[colnum]] = col
                    colnum += 1
            rownum += 1
            if rec:
                client.put(('test', 'demo', str(rownum)), rec)
            rec = {}

    t1 = time.time()
    load_time = t1 - t0

    t2 = time.time()
    for i in range(2,500002):
        (key, metadata, record) = client.get(('test', 'demo', str(i)))
        # print(record)
    t3 = time.time()

    read_time = t3 - t2


    return [load_time , read_time]
```

Comment: Are you planning to write your application in python? Python isn't the language I would choose for a benchmark.

Comment: That said, your benchmark would benefit from using async apis as well as running a process per CPU core.

Comment: Yes. Python would be the language for the app, so i guess it makes sense to use Python in the analysis as well.

Comment: Also, i find it weird that when using my local machine, my code runs fine but when it's on a ec2 instance, it's becoming significantly slow.

Comment: On your local machine you probably don't have any latency between the application and the server (assuming that is also running on your local machine).

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried running on a single instance and works significantly better. Also, sorry for the multiple questions. I'll make sure to add 5 stars on community support in my recommendation. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, well I wouldn't suggest testing your app to run on the same machine as the server, assuming this is something more than a toy project. Eventually, you may want to either scale the app or the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your Python application going to run as a single process, or will it be a multi-process approach, such as fastCGI?

If you're trying to benchmark, make sure it's simulating how your application will run. To write lots of rows, then read lots of rows, all from a single process, doesn't usually simulate anything realistic. Perhaps in your case it does, but if not, make your sample code match the real access pattern.

Also, you should deploy your benchmark in a similar way to the application. Don't run benchmarks on the same machine as the server nodes, if that's not how it'll be in production.